# Recompiling SASS on WordPress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, underscores-wp

I've edited the scss file on my WordPress theme but I'm unsure how to recompile the CSS, the functions.php file says:

```
main.scss: Compiled Framework source + custom styles.
```

Do I need to manually compile it or is it something that should happen automatically?

I'm using the bootstrap starter theme from them.es if that makes any difference: https://them.es/starter-bootstrap/

Comment: Would be interested in knowing the result of this